# How to search for files in directory that start with String

Tags: java, file, file-io, linked-list

I have a directory full of text files. The naming convention of these files is {userName} + {dayOfYear}

```
SuperMan201
JamesBond056
JamesBond101
JamesBond093
JamesBondImposter004
SuperMan051
JamesBond057
JamesBond004
```

I want to search through my files for files that start with Jamesbond. How can I get the first instance of a text file that starts with Jamesbond and not get JamesBondImposter matching my search.

I have a LinkedHashSet that stores the usernames of the users that have text files in the directory. Essentially I want to get the first instance of a JamesBond text file read the file,move the file to another directory, then read subsequent files if they exist; and then move on to the next username in the LinkedList.

Comment: Represent the files by splitting as explained in your earlier question. Use a `SortedSet` instead of a `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select files from directory take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter) - just write the filter that will match what you want

Comment: java.io.File is obsolete and should not be used anymore, as its methods do not properly report errors.  Use [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache commons-io (listFiles and iterateFiles methods). Usually the code looks something like this:

```
File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("James*");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

if(files!=null && files.length > 0)
{

 your desired file is files[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you can do this:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(fullPathOfDirectory);

Stream<Path> jamesBondFiles = Files.list(dir).filter(path ->
    path.getFileName().toString().matches("JamesBond\\d+"));

Iterator<Path> i = jamesBondFiles.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Path file = i.next();
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file)) {
        // Read and process file
    }
}
```

If you're using Java 7, or don't want to use a Stream, you can do:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(fullPathOfDirectory);

final PathMatcher matcher =
    dir.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("regex:JamesBond\\d+");

DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> filter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        return matcher.matches(path.getFileName());
    }
};

try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, filter)) {
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    for (Path file : ds) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
            // Read and process file
        }
    }
}
```